# Why does my react component re-render infinite while hook with useContext doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React with typescript and Material UI as framework.
If you choose a line in the dataset table, the context "chosenDataset" is set, but crashes the app because it re-renders too many times.
I want that it dynamically adds tabs and panels with data from an API. It gets the data(here the mappings aka the SelectionMatrix) but it is stuck on the first one. I guess because it doesn't get further because of the re-rendering.
What is triggering the re-rendering or calling the hook. And how do I change that?
I tried to use useMemo to prevent the re-rendering, but it's not possible to use it with hooks.

In case that it helps, here is the main component causing the error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-antonelli-epytmz?file=/src/mappingTabs.tsx

Comment: Right before `render`, if `mappings is available, you are setting it to state. That will cause another render cycle. But on next cycle, you have same check and mappings would still be defined, so you set it again and loop goes on

Comment: Could you tell me what line? And do you have an idea of how to solve this?